# Asyncfileupload doesn't work in webusercontrol

Tags: c#, asp.net, asyncfileupload

I'm having a problem with a Webusercontrol that has an asyncfileupload control.
My websusercontrol is being loaded in a placeholder control  that's wrapped by an updatepanel.Due to asyncpostback, I have to load and clear the placeholder's controls.

The webusercontrol works flawlessly, except the asyncfileupload, which doesn't want to upload at all. I can assure that the code is without error, because I used to have the webusercontrol running as an *.aspx site.

I guess that the problem is the fact that the control has to be cleared and reloaded with every asyncpostback ?

Answer (score 2):

I think issues occur once you place your AsyncFileUpload control inside a dynamically-loaded custom user control.

I managed to [get around this issue after reading this link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1477331.aspx/1?AsyncFileUpload+inside+a+GridView+inside+an+UpdatePanel#3443999)

Basically, I **placed a dummy AsyncFileUpload control on the parent .aspx page**.

E.g. `Default.aspx`

```
    <span style="display:none">
        <asp:AsyncFileUpload ID="DummyAsyncFileUpload" runat="server" />
    </span>
```

Note that the AsyncFileUpload control is hidden from users, but still visible to ASP.NET.

My theory is this:

In order to upload files, you have to post your form's content using a different encoding type (`multipart/form-data`).

When you place your AsyncFileUpload inside an UpdatePanel, ASP.NET for whatever reason, does not set the encoding type at all, and leaves it empty.

e.g. `document.forms[0].enctype = ''`

Thus, when you post your form, it does not know what to do with file upload.

By placing the dummy AsyncFileUpload on the Default.aspx page, ASP.NET detects the presence of the FileUpload control, and will set the encoding type accordingly.

e.g. `document.forms[0].enctype = 'multipart/form-data'`